# Как скопировать в mysql таблицы из одной базы в другую, которые начинаются на wp_?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
USE wordpress1;

CREATE TABLE products LIKE wordpress.products;

INSERT INTO products  
    SELECT * FROM wordpress.products;
```

Этот код позволяет копировать таблицу по одной. А как сделать что бы скопировал все таблицы начинающиеся на "wp_"?

Comment: Написать хранимую процедуру, которая получит список таблиц из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES и организует итерирование по ним. С динамическим SQL, ясное дело.

Comment: Прежде чем этим заниматься на всякий случай покури матчасть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/504949